# Why is "node ." taking so long?

Tags: discord.js

I have made a discord bot using JavaScript. When I use "node ." in the terminal to run the file and make it active, it doesn't work. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you set up *`node .`* as a script in your `package.json` file?

If you haven't yet, head over to your package.json file, within the scripts add `"node .": "node index.js"`, so it looks something like this, remember to replace index.js with the name of your main file.

```
  "scripts": {
    "node .": "node index.js"
  },
```

If you have done this and it still goes to error, please send the error that is displayed